# Using bitwise OR 0 to floor a number

Tags: javascript, floating-point, bit-manipulation

A colleague of mine stumbled upon a method to floor float numbers using a bitwise or:

```
var a = 13.6 | 0; //a == 13
```

We were talking about it and wondering a few things.

- How does it work? Our theory was that using such an operator casts the number to an integer, thus removing the fractional part
- Does it have any advantages over doing `Math.floor`? Maybe it's a bit faster? (pun not intended)
- Does it have any disadvantages? Maybe it doesn't work in some cases? Clarity is an obvious one, since we had to figure it out, and well, I'm writing this question.

Thanks.

Comment: Disadvantage: it only works up to 2^31−1 which is around 2 billion (10^9). The max Number value is around 10^308 btw.

Comment: Example: `3000000000.1 | 0` evaluates to -1294967296. So this method can't be applied for money calculations (especially in cases where you multiply by 100 to avoid decimal numbers).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Floats shouldn't be used in money calculations also

Comment: I personally like `~~` for bitwise flooring.  `var a = ~~13.6; // a == 13`

Comment: It is not flooring, it is **truncating** (rounding towards 0).

Comment: | 0 is faster. Check the benchmark: http://jsben.ch/#/MJvaN

Comment: it's not rounding either - just like @joe's answer said it is casting to an int. The correct way to state this when seeing `| 0` is simply "truncating to int" IMHO

Comment: The better 'flooring' could be: `parseInt(""+13.6)`, but it converts float to int.

Comment: @GeorgeReith "Floats shouldn't be used in money calculations also". Why not?

Comment: @sequence try typing `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` in a JavaScript console. If your language supports it, you should use a decimal type. If not, store cents instead.

Comment: @GeorgeReith unfortunately, with JS, *every* number is a floating point number. However, there do exist JS libraries that allow arbitrary precision numbers by keeping the internal array’s numbers less than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` which is `2^53 - 1`. So, the library could, for example, keep it’s internal array’s values under `2^32`. In fact, that’s how JS crypto libraries work.

Comment: @ColeJohnson indeed, what I meant was only use whole numbers if you only have access to floats. Or as AlexTurpin put it "store cents".

Comment: Now that `BigInt` is in the language you should use that where possible (outside of cryptography).

Answer (score 196, accepted):

> How does it work? Our theory was that using such an operator casts the
>   number to an integer, thus removing the fractional part

All bitwise operations except unsigned right shift, `>>>`, work on signed 32-bit integers. So using bitwise operations will convert a float to an integer.

> Does it have any advantages over doing Math.floor? Maybe it's a bit
>   faster? (pun not intended)

http://jsperf.com/or-vs-floor/2 seems slightly faster

> Does it have any disadvantages? Maybe it doesn't work in some cases?
>   Clarity is an obvious one, since we had to figure it out, and well,
>   I'm writting this question.

- Will not pass jsLint.
- 32-bit signed integers only
- Odd Comparative behavior: `Math.floor(NaN) === NaN`, while `(NaN | 0) === 0`

Comment: wow that's a HUGE performance difference, doesn't it round the wrong way around for negative numbers though?

Comment: @harold indeed, because it does not in fact round, merely truncates.

Comment: Another possible disadvantage is that `Math.floor(NaN) === NaN`, while `(NaN | 0) === 0`. That difference might be important in some applications.

Comment: Your jsperf is yielding performance information for empty loops on chrome due to loop invariant code motion.  A slightly better perf test would be: http://jsperf.com/floor-performance/2

Comment: Elm is using it to decode integers here: https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/3.0.0/src/Native/Json.js#L57.

Comment: Is the conversion specific to JavaScript or common to bitwise operations in most other languages?

Comment: This is a standard part of `asm.js` (where I first learned about it). It's faster if for no other reason because it's not calling a function on the `Math` object, a function that could at anytime be replaced as in `Math.floor = function(...)`.

Comment: `(value | 0) === value` could be used to check that a value is in fact an integer and only an integer (as in the Elm source code @dwayne-crooks linked). And `foo = foo | 0` could be used to coerce any value to an integer (where 32-bit numbers are truncated and all non-numbers become 0).

Comment: @gman Also, with some JS interpreters (thinking of V8), there exists two types of `Number`, the floating point (JS spec compliment), and a 32-bit integer. When V8 sees the `| 0`, it changes the type internally to the integer version (for faster calculations). Then, *if* an operation requires a fractional component, it’ll switch its internal representation back to floating point. Very neat. https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds

Comment: "Math.floor(NaN) === NaN" is WRONG, it evaluates false. Maybe rewrite that as "Math.floor(NaN) returns NaN".  Reason: "NaN === anything" is always false, so "NaN === NaN" is false!  NaN is very much a special-case in all of the comparison operators.

Answer (score 45):

This is *truncation* as opposed to flooring.  Howard's answer is sort of correct; But I would add that `Math.floor` does exactly what it is supposed to with respect to negative numbers.  Mathematically, that is what a floor is.

In the case you described above, the programmer was more interested in *truncation* or chopping the decimal completely off.  Although, the syntax they used sort of obscures the fact that they are converting the float to an int.

Comment: This is the correct answer, accepted one is not. Add to it that `Math.floor(8589934591.1)` produces expected result, `8589934591.1 | 0` **DOES NOT**.

Comment: You are correct Chad. When I test `Math.floor(-5.5)`  it will return me `-6`. So if we use bitwise, it will use bitwise `-5.5 >> 0` it will return me the correct answer `-5`

Answer (score 29):

In ECMAScript 6, the equivalent of `|0` is [Math.trunc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc), kind of I should say:

> Returns the integral part of a number by removing any fractional digits. It just truncate the dot and the digits behind it, no matter whether the argument is a positive number or a negative number.

```
Math.trunc(13.37)   // 13
Math.trunc(42.84)   // 42
Math.trunc(0.123)   //  0
Math.trunc(-0.123)  // -0
Math.trunc("-1.123")// -1
Math.trunc(NaN)     // NaN
Math.trunc("foo")   // NaN
Math.trunc()        // NaN
```

Comment: Except the fact that `Math.trunc()` work with number higher or equal to 2^31 and `| 0` does not

Answer (score 20):

Javascript represents `Number` as [Double Precision 64-bit Floating numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Double-precision_64_bit).

`Math.floor` works with this in mind.

Bitwise operations work in 32bit **signed** integers. 32bit signed integers use first bit as negative signifier and the other 31 bits are the number. Because of this, the min and max number allowed 32bit signed numbers are -2,147,483,648 and 2147483647 (0x7FFFFFFFF), respectively.

So when you're doing `| 0`, you're essentially doing is `& 0xFFFFFFFF`. This means, any number that is represented as 0x80000000 (2147483648) or greater will return as a negative number.

For example:

```
 // Safe
 (2147483647.5918 & 0xFFFFFFFF) ===  2147483647
 (2147483647      & 0xFFFFFFFF) ===  2147483647
 (200.59082098    & 0xFFFFFFFF) ===  200
 (0X7FFFFFFF      & 0xFFFFFFFF) ===  0X7FFFFFFF
 
 // Unsafe
 (2147483648      & 0xFFFFFFFF) === -2147483648
 (-2147483649     & 0xFFFFFFFF) ===  2147483647
 (0x80000000      & 0xFFFFFFFF) === -2147483648
 (3000000000.5    & 0xFFFFFFFF) === -1294967296
```

Also. Bitwise operations don't "floor". They **truncate**, which is the same as saying, they round closest to `0`. Once you go around to negative numbers, `Math.floor` rounds *down* while bitwise start rounding *up*.

As I said before, `Math.floor` is safer because it operates with 64bit floating numbers. Bitwise **is faster**, yes, but limited to 32bit signed scope.

To summarize:

- Bitwise works the same if you work from `0 to 2147483647`.
- Bitwise is 1 number off if you work from `-2147483647 to 0`.
- Bitwise is completely different for numbers less than `-2147483648` and greater than `2147483647`.

If you *really* want to tweak performance and use both:

```
function floor(n) {
    if (n >= 0 && n < 0x80000000) {
      return n & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    }
    if (n > -0x80000000 && n < 0) {
      const bitFloored = n & 0xFFFFFFFF;
      if (bitFloored === n) return n;
      return bitFloored - 1;
    }
    return Math.floor(n);
}
```

---

Just to add `Math.trunc` works like bitwise operations. So you can do this:

```
function trunc(n) {
    if (n > -0x80000000 && n < 0x80000000) {
      return n & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    }
    return Math.trunc(n);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Your first point is correct. The number is cast to an integer and thus any decimal digits are removed. Please note, that `Math.floor` rounds to the next integer towards minus infinity and thus gives a different result when applied to negative numbers.

Answer (score 5):

- The specs say that it is converted to an integer:

  > Let lnum be ToInt32(lval).
- Performance: this has been tested at [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/math-round-vs-hack/25.) before.

*note: dead link to spec removed*

Answer (score 0):

```
var myNegInt = -1 * Math.pow(2, 32);
var myFloat = 0.010203040506070809;
var my64BitFloat = myNegInt - myFloat;
var trunc1 = my64BitFloat | 0;
var trunc2 = ~~my64BitFloat;
var trunc3 = my64BitFloat ^ 0;
var trunc4 = my64BitFloat - my64BitFloat % 1;
var trunc5 = parseInt(my64BitFloat);
var trunc6 = Math.floor(my64BitFloat);
console.info(my64BitFloat);
console.info(trunc1);
console.info(trunc2);
console.info(trunc3);
console.info(trunc4);
console.info(trunc5);
console.info(trunc6);
```

IMO: The question "How does it work?", "Does it have any advantages over doing Math.floor?", "Does it have any disadvantages?" pale in comparison to "**Is it at all logical to use it for this purpose?**"

I think, before you try to get clever with your code, you may want to run these. My advice; just move along, there is nothing to see here. Using bitwise to save a few operations and having that matter to you at all, usually means your code architecture needs work. As far as why it may work *sometimes*, well a stopped clock is accurate twice a day, that does not make it useful. These operators have their uses, but not in this context.