# What does ~~ do in JavaScript/node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the “double tilde” (~~) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971645/what-is-the-double-tilde-operator-in-javascript)

I found this snip of code in a node.js library's source. What effect does `~~` have on the `input` variable?

```
inArray[3] = ~~input;
```

It's also used in other ways:

```
return ~~ ((a - b) / 864e5 / 7 + 1.5);
```

Comment: Makes code confusing to read -_-. I hate how people are doing this recently; it makes me very angry.

Comment: Heh, this is even more annoying than the double `!!`..

Comment: @jasonbar can't search for ~~, but I did look :( For some reason "double tilde" never occurred to me! :)

Comment: @Kato: Just Google for a list of operators, then when you find a page of them, hit Ctrl-F (or Cmd-F), ~. :p

Comment: @ElliotBonneville I started on Google with operators in mind. Sometimes it's just easier to ask Humans. ;)

Comment: What library is that by the way? Curious as to the purpose of `return ~~ ((a - b) / 864e5 / 7 + 1.5);`. Probably a fast estimation of some sort but still

Comment: @Xeon06 [moment.js](https://github.com/timrwood/moment), the code is [here](https://github.com/timrwood/moment/blob/master/moment.js) on line 155

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `~` operator flips the bits of its operand. Using it twice flips the bits, then flips them again, returning a standard Javascript value equivalent to the operand, but in integer form. It's shorthand for `parseInt(myInt)`.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it would be something of the sort. For some reason, I couldn't figure out how to Google it; must needs more tea :)

Comment: No problem, see my comment on your question for how to Google operators. :p

Comment: @Kato Search google for "tilde JavaScript" and press I Feel lucky: http://dreaminginjavascript.wordpress.com/2008/07/04/28/

Comment: @AndreasAL roger, searched for "tea plus javascript" and feel much luckier.

Answer (score 11):

It's a hackish way to truncate a value, a bit like what `Math.floor` does, except this behaves differently for negative numbers. For example, truncating -15.9 (`~~-15.9`) gives `-15`, but flooring it will always round towards the lowest number, so `Math.floor(-15.9)` will give `16`.

Another way to do it [is to OR with zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487977/using-bitwise-or-0-to-floor-a-number).

```
var a = 15.9 | 0; //a = 15
```

Comment: re: Differently for negative values -- how so?

Comment: @Kato added explanation to post.

Comment: It looks like ~~ is quite a bit faster than Math.floor; not that it's enough to matter in most cases.

Comment: @Kato yeah, it sounds like premature optimization to me to use this everwhere.

Comment: i prefer `~~` since `~~idx === idx` iff `idx` is integer. using `|0` you would need braces, i.e. `(idx|0) === idx`

Answer (score 2):

It converts the value to an integer.