# Why does JSHint argue against bitwise operators? How should I express this code?

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint

I am using this bit of JavaScript to generate a UID:

(original:)

```
//If ID has not been defined then generate a new unique ID.
if(!id){
    id = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) { var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8); return v.toString(16); });
}
```

(formatted so it can be read:)

```
// If ID has not been defined then generate a new unique ID.
if (!id) {
    id = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(
        /[xy]/g, 
        function (c) { 
            var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, 
                v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8); 
            return v.toString(16); 
        }
    );
}
```

JSHint does not like the use of bitwise OR and AND operators. I was wondering how I could rewrite this to be more 'standard friendly.'

EDIT: JSHint states:

```
Line 8: id = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) { var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8); return v.toString(16); });
Unexpected use of '|'.

Line 8: id = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) { var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8); return v.toString(16); });
Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.

Line 8: id = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) { var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8); return v.toString(16); });
Unexpected use of '&'.

Line 8: id = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) { var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8); return v.toString(16); });
Unexpected use of '|'.
```

Comment: Does it show any message in addition "I don't like it"? PS: working with bits using bitwise operators is a standard and friendly way

Comment: I added in the messages provided.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Put

```
/*jshint bitwise: false*/
```

in the top of your file

A list of available options: http://jshint.com/docs/options/

Comment: Doesn't answer the question of _why_.

Comment: @Snekse: obviously because bitwise operators are quite rare in JS and most likely user has confused `&&` with `&`

Comment: @zerkms, I'm using VS2012, and this didn't seem to work. The errors still appear.

Comment: @series0ne: ask another question then, with thorough explanation of what you have and what you experience.

Comment: In WebStorm you can also disable this warning directly in *File->Settings->Javascript->Code Quality Tools->JSHint->Enforcing Options->Warn about using bitwise operators*, whitout the need to pollute your source code.

Comment: @luciopaiva: the advice is more actual for CI servers

Comment: @LucioPaiva what does the _false_ in _bitwise:false_ really do?

Comment: @SaadMalik well, it tells JSHint to ignore bitwise operators (i.e., disables the validator, setting it to *false*). Don't know if I understood your question correctly, though.

Comment: @LucioPaiva what is the difference between _bitwise:false_ and _bitwise:true_ ? The docs mention for _globals_, _false_ = read-only, _true_ = read/write variable. But what does it mean for options?

Comment: You can also disable it locally by wrapping it around your statement:`/*jshint bitwise: false*/ your statement /*jshint bitwise: true*/`

Comment: So any code, as good as it may be, needing to parse binary data, or compute a numerical algorithm involving bitwise operations (checksum, hash etc), requires this directive?

Answer (score 17):

According to [JSHint docs](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#bitwise), it is because

> "Bitwise operators are very rare in JavaScript programs"

As others have mentioned, you can disable the `bitwise` JSHint option to squelch the warnings.

Comment: The only answer that answers the question, and should be accepted. But the reason why JSHint (and TSLint) flags bitwise operations is quite dumb actually. There are proper though rare usage scenarios for bitwise operators, and for these scenarios you never should use anything but bitwise operators.

Answer (score 6):

You've jammed so much code into one line (why??) that you can't tell what jshint is pointing out to you.  I've reformatted the code, and I see this:

```
var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0,
```

What is the `| 0` doing there? It's a needless no-op.  UPDATE: seems to be a way to int-ify a float.

Jshint seems to not like other things, but at least get rid of this.  And spread your code out so that you (and others) can read it.

Comment: I am just using the second solution provided here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript

That perceived no-op exists in this solution with 200+ votes. Is it really not doing anything?

EDIT: Yeah, the bitwise OR definitely does something. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487977/using-bitwise-or-0-to-floor-a-number

Comment: Blah, it could be a weird Javascript way to say, truncate to int.

Comment: I think that the code should be rewritten to use Math.round(). That incurs an overhead, but would be more clear as to what is happening.

Comment: @SeanAnderson - It's a truncate, so `Math.floor` is more appropriate as a replacement. Bitwise OR is also very quick in comparison to `Math.floor`. The reason JSHint / JSLint warn about it, is because they're often typos, and not intentional.

Comment: @SeanAnderson - you'll note that bitwise shifts aren't warned by jslint / jshint, so you shouldn't avoid using bitwise operators. However, try not to be too clever with your code, it becomes a maintenance nightmare. If you have a clearer way to express something, e.g. `Math.floor()` in this instance, use that instead. Avoid premature optimisation.

Answer (score 2):

About the "Why argue against bitwise operators". I like this from [TSLint docs](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-bitwise/)

> Bitwise operators are often typos (...)
>   They also can be an indicator of overly clever code which decreases maintainability.

Answer (score -1):

this works fine for me:

```
return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g,
    function(c: string) {
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16), 
            v = c === 'x' ? r : (r % 4 + 4);
        return v.toString(16);          
    }).toUpperCase();
```