# countdown timer using moment.js mm:ss format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using this [moment.js](http://momentjs.com)

Here's the sample code:

```
var mytimer= moment().format('00:60');

setInterval(counter,500);

function counter(){
     mytimer--; // its return NaN error
     sym.$("Text").html(mytimer);
}
```

How can I make it count down like this?

00:60
00:59
... 
00:00

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use moment in this case.  It strikes me as a library better suited for formatting dates, not timers.  Please see my example below.  It uses a callback so you can reuse this to do any number of things.

```js
    function MyTimer(callback, val) {
        val = val || 60; 
        var timer=setInterval(function() { 
            callback(val);
            if(val-- <= 0) { 
                clearInterval(timer); 
            } 
        }, 1000);
    }
    new MyTimer(function(val) {
        var timerMsg = "00:" + (val >= 10 ? val : "0" + val);
        document.getElementById("timer").textContent = timerMsg; 
    });
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not using moment, however this is in the format you want

[Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618355/the-simplest-possible-javascript-countdown-timer).

http://jsfiddle.net/robbmj/czu6scth/2/

```
window.onload = function() {

      var display = document.querySelector('#time'),
          timer = new CountDownTimer(5);

      timer.onTick(format).onTick(restart).start();

      function restart() {
        if (this.expired()) {
          setTimeout(function() { timer.start(); }, 1000);
        }
      }

      function format(minutes, seconds) {
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        display.textContent = minutes + ':' + seconds;
      }
    };
```

This will display in  00:00 format.