# How to create a timer using JSF/Richfaces, and call an action when timer reaches 0?

Tags: jsf, timer, popup, richfaces

I currently have a pop up that shows in my app in which users have to enter data.

I want a 5 minutes timer so after this time, if they did not fill out the data, the pop up will close.

Basically, after 5 minutes, I want a certain method of the bean to be called, which will as a result, close the pop up.

I know how to call the action on the bean, but I can't find any info on how to create a timer, and display it in the pop up. I need the user to be able to see the remaining time.

I currently have a `<rich:modalPanel>` in order to display the pop-up.

Is this only possible?

Comment: javascript setTimeout() to click in a hidden button

Comment: How would I display the current remaining time in the popup?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618355/the-simplest-possible-javascript-countdown-timer

Comment: Always write about things like RF version. I assume you're using some not supported RF 3.x version. If you want just close the popup then JavaScript would be much better, no need to connect the serwer. I you want make some action in been then I'd also use JavaScript which fires some `a4j:jsFunction`

Comment: Of course I meant bean not been :-]