# How add format hours/minutes/seconds For Countdown timer

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I confused about timer countdown,
I have try to change but stuck with hours format,
I have get code countdown like this below from link 
[The simplest possible JavaScript countdown timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618355/the-simplest-possible-javascript-countdown-timer) :

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var start = Date.now(),
        diff,
        minutes,
        seconds;
    function timer() {
        // get the number of seconds that have elapsed since 
        // startTimer() was called
        diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

        // does the same job as parseInt truncates the float
        minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
        seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds; 

        if (diff <= 0) {
            // add one second so that the count down starts at the full duration
            // example 05:00 not 04:59
            start = Date.now() + 1000;
        }
    };
    // we don't want to wait a full second before the timer starts
    timer();
    setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

I want add hours in this javascript with format 60:60:60 / hh/mm/ss

Thank youuu :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ramanbedi1989/8m9mnxm0/) can help you.
here is the code to display the hours:

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var start = Date.now(),
        diff,
        hours,
        minutes,
        seconds;
    function timer() {
        // get the number of seconds that have elapsed since 
        // startTimer() was called
        diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

        // does the same job as parseInt truncates the float

        minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
        seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

        if(minutes >= 60){
           hours = (minutes / 60) | 0;
           minutes = (minutes % 60) | 0;
        }else{
           hours = 0;
        }

        hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds; 

        if (diff <= 0) {
            // add one second so that the count down starts at the full duration
            // example 05:00 not 04:59
            start = Date.now() + 1000;
        }
    };
    // we don't want to wait a full second before the timer starts
    timer();
    setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 60 * 5,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```