# Countdown timer with hundredths?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a countdown timer in the format of 00:00:00 (minutes, seconds, and hundredths). Right the now the way I set up my countdown timer, is to make sure the user inputs in the format of 00:00:00 (which has to be). From there the countdown time should commence when they click the start button. I see that it does somewhat of a countdown, but I'm not sure what could be the problem with my implementation. The hundredths is not decrementing correctly for some reason. It should start of as 10:00:00 (10 mins) and go to 09:59:99.. 09:59:98, etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Countdown Timer</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var running = 0;
      var hundreds = 0;

      function validTime() {
      var setTime = document.getElementById("timeEntered").value; 
      var regex = /^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/;
      if (regex.test(setTime)) {
            document.getElementById("timeAlert").innerHTML = "<span class='valid'>Valid</span>";
            return (true);
            } else {
            document.getElementById("timeAlert").innerHTML = "<span class='error'>Invalid time entered. Please make sure it's in the format 00:00:00</span>";
            return (false);
            }
      }

      function correctTime(){
         if (validTime()){
            countdownTimer();
            return true;
         }else{
            alert("Please correct your inputted time.");
            return false;
         }
      }

      function countdownTimer() {
         var time = document.getElementById("timeEntered").value;
         var a = time.split(":");
         var timeToSeconds = (+a[0]) * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);
         if(parseInt(timeToSeconds) <= 600 ) {
            startPause();
         }else{
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Sorry. Time range cannot exceed 10 mins.";
         }
      }

      function startPause(){
         var time = document.getElementById("timeEntered").value;
         var a = time.split(":");
         var timeToSeconds = (+a[0]) * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);
         if(running == 0){
            running = 1;
            decrement();
            document.getElementById("startPause").innerHTML = "Start/Stop";
         }else{
            running = 0;
            document.getElementById("startPause").innerHTML = "Resume";
         }
      }

      var hundreds = 0;
      function decrement(){
         var time = document.getElementById("timeEntered").value;
         var a = time.split(":");
         var timeToSeconds = (+a[0]) * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);
         if(running == 1){        
               var mins = Math.round((timeToSeconds - 30)/60);
               var secs = timeToSeconds % 60;
               //var hundredths = timeToSeconds % 100;
               if(mins < 10) {
                  mins = "0" + mins;
               }

               if(secs < 10) {
                  secs = "0" + secs;
               }

               document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = mins + ":" + secs + ":" + hundreds;
               if (hundreds === 0){
                  if(timeToSeconds ===0){
                     clearInterval(countdownTimer);
                     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Time's Up.";
                  }else{
                     timeToSeconds--;
                     hundreds = 100;
                  }
                  }else{
                     hundreds--;
                  }
                  var countdownTimer = setInterval('decrement()', 10)
          }
      }

</script>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Countdown Timer</h1>
   <div id="mainCont">
      <p>Please enter the desired time:
        <input type="text" id="timeEntered" onblur="validTime();">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="timeAlert"></span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <button id="startPause" onclick="correctTime()">Start/Stop</button>
      </p>
      <div id="output">00:00:00</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The simplest possible JavaScript countdown timer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618355/the-simplest-possible-javascript-countdown-timer)

Comment: This is a countdown timer with minutes seconds hundredths. Not hours.

Comment: You can easily modify it..

Comment: Please any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've got a nasty, nasty bug in the ms parts. It freezes up the browser window as well

Comment: I really feel you should try and debug it your self

Comment: I'm trying to debug too.

Comment: I have some working code that gets you 1/100 of a second. Is that cool? Natually, with a 00:00:00 format, you can only have 100th of a second because you ahve only 2 digits to display

Comment: uhhhh could you run a snippet or use jsfiddle?

Comment: I;m not much experienced in JS. However, i can only read some code so that i how i designed it. Give me 5 minutes I will post it properly in the SO snippet format

Answer (score 1):

I think @bholagabbar's code needs rewriting into hundreths of a second rather than in seconds.

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds, dispms;
    setInterval(function () {
        dispms=parseInt(timer % 100,10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer / 100, 10);
        minutes = parseInt(seconds / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(seconds % 60, 10);
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        dispms = dispms < 10 ? "0" + dispms : dispms;
        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds+":"+dispms;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 10);  //hundreths of a second - 1000 would be 1 second
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5 * 100, //hundreths of second
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted but I have some working code for a timer that counts up to the given input (in seconds) which includes the 1/100th of a second. If you want to include ms as you mentioned, you will need 3 0's or  ':000' for the display int the end. Here is the code. How will of course, have to mod it for your scenario but the timer is implemented perfe

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds, dispms;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
        dispms=parseInt((timer)%100,10);
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        dispms = dispms < 10 ? "0" + dispms : dispms;
        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds+":"+dispms;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
<body>
    <div>Registration closes in <span id="time"></span> minutes!</div>
</body>
```

I think you will have to make changes only in the HTML part. Rest of the logic in my code is fine for a general timer. You will have to pass in the seconds as an argument, that is all

Comment: hmmm not quite. The user has to be able to enter in the time format 10:00:00. (10 mins). Once that happens it should decrement to 09:59:99... 09:59:98... etc. Basically seconds change until the hundredths reach 00. Also I'm trying to refrain from using query since I'm not too familiar with it.