# Simple Javascript timer with system date

Tags: javascript

I want to make a javascript timer for a countdown of 7 days since it is first run.

Here is the scenario:

1. The html file will given to 100 students
2. So the timer will start whenever one opens the html file
3. If the user restarts the computer the time will not affect

Dont know how its done..

[The simplest possible JavaScript countdown timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618355/the-simplest-possible-javascript-countdown-timer)

Comment: *If the user changes the system date.. then the timer should not change

Comment: Simply put, this is not possible without a backend.  There has to be a server that can be told to start the countdown or show the current time if it has already started.  What you're asking is possible *locally* without a server, but only if the same page is accessed on the same computer.

Comment: html page will be same.. computer will be different.. like the timer will triggered once the html is opened on a particular computer

Comment: You can save timer's start time in localStorage. But use can simply drop it if he knows javascript a bit.

Comment: @S.Nadezhnyy That would be local.  He clearly wants the countdown to work across all computers which have the page.

Comment: exactly.. the timer will start once the user openes.. whether he/she opens it after a year.. the timer will be of 7 days

Comment: @Pankaj Badera Is timer unique per user or is it shared among all users ?

Answer (score 1):

This [can be accomplished **locally**](http://atornblad.se/javascript-countdown-using-localstorage) *(that means that each user gets their own counter)* by saving the value of `Date.now()` into `localStorage`. Then, when reopening the html file, you read from `localStorage` and compare the value to the current `Date.now()`.

What you can do with this timer is then very limited, unless you serve this html file of yours from a server.

```
(function() {
    var started = localStorage['started'];
    if (started) {
        // This is not the first time the user opens this file
        // How long has it been?

        var diff = Date.now() - started;

        if (diff >= 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7) {
            // At least one week has passed. Do something here.
        } else {
            // Less than a week has passed. Do something else here.
        }
    } else {
        // This is the first time the user opens this file 

        localStorage['started'] = Date.now();

        // Do something else here to welcome the user...
    }
})();
```

Date.now reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

Just remember that there is no security at all in this. You are doing this on **the user's browser**, and the user has full control over that environment. A simple **clear cache** will delete the saved value from `localStorage`.

I have used this method to create a project time clock that runs completely locally.

Comment: Although this is a nice way to handle it but what happens if the user opens the link or html file in another browser ?

Comment: That other browser will get its own instance of the countdown. If that is a concern for the poster, they should not use a client-side solution. What they are after probably requires a server-side solution with some kind of authentication.

Comment: thanks @AndersTornblad :) let me try this

Comment: This doesn't seem to satisfy his requirements.  He clearly wants this to work between everyone having the page link.  Really the main difference is  porting this logic to the server side and simply accessing it from the client.

Comment: This is what i want :  The timer will start once the user openes.. whether he/she opens it after a year.. the timer will be of 7 days

Comment: @PankajBadera Then I misunderstood your requirements.  My apologies to Anders then.

Comment: I didn't interpret the requirements that way, Neil. To me it seems that he wants one counter per user, but I'm not sure. I might be wrong. In that case, this solution is completely wrong.

Comment: Like @Neil said ... doesn't seem like it can happen without some kind of server involvement. You need a central place for authentication and running of timers. Also consider the time zone differences.

Comment: @Aukhan Oh man, time zone differences.. that'd be fun to have to deal with.

Comment: The counter is unique per user. They *probably* won't change time zones during this time. And even if they did, Date.now() is unix time, which is UTC.

Comment: @AndersTornblad Consider that it's just local javascript.  At any time someone could manually set localStorage['started'] forward to whatever they like.  It seems to me that time zone issues are less critical by comparison.  It's fine for an experiment, but to be practical, you'd need to involve a server.

Comment: @Anders Date.Now() would be the timezone of the system that JS is running on.

Comment: Niel: I am saying that in my answer. The user has complete dominion over the browser.
Aukhan: The now() method returns the milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC up until now as a Number. So no timezone problems.

Comment: @AndersTornblad It isn't a criticism of your answer, in fact I upvoted it.  My point was only "reader beware".

Comment: I didn't take it as criticism, as I totally agree. The OP should not do this if there are any concerns for security, data integrity or anything else. :)