# Creating Javascript countdown from currentvalue to targetvalue and change numbers every sec

Tags: javascript, html, count

```js
currentValue = 708295;
targetValue = 0;

function count() {
  if (currentValue > targetValue) {
    currentValue -= 1
  } else if (currentValue < targetValue) {
    currentValue += 1
  }
  document.getElementById('timeTo').innerHTML =
    'Total wordcount:'+ currentValue.toString();
  changeTime = 1000;
  if (Math.abs(currentValue - targetValue) <0) {
    changeTime = 1000 - Math.abs(currentValue - targetValue);
  }
  setTimeout(count,changeTime/1);
}
count()
```

```html
<h1 id="timeTo">Starting</h1>
```

any help will be very useful, i m trying to learn javascricpt and i want to create count down.

I want number to go down every sec but so far i have created the function to count the number but its counting too fast

ANy help or any suggestions

Thanks

Comment: You can view a complete example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618355/the-simplest-possible-javascript-countdown-timer

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout second argument is miliseconds value, it should be set to 1000 if you want to *tick* every second.

Comment: Thank you , one more question what is the best way to add "," to 708295

Comment: What do you mean by _add "," to 708295_ ?

Comment: I want to add comma to 708295 so it will look like 708,295

Comment: I recommend using [numberFormatter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat). console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat().format(123456));