# Multiple countdown timer

Tags: javascript, html, timer, countdowntimer

This js countdown timer is working fine but on multiple timers it is only working on the last div. How will it run on all the divs ? It should work on all the divs as there will be more than two timers. Any guidance will be really appreciated.

This is my code:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m47spzer/)

HTML & JS.

```
    <div id="timez1"></div>
    <div id="timez2"></div>

      var m = 1;
  function countdowny(){
  if(daysy == 0 && hoursy == 0 && minutesy == 0 && secondsy == 0){
    //seconds = 0;
    timez.innerHTML = "Auction Ended";
    }
    else{
      if(secondsy == 0){
          secondsy = 59;
          minutesy--;
        }else{
        secondsy--;
        }
        if(minutesy == -1){
        minutesy = 59;
          hoursy--;
         }
         if(hoursy == -1){
           hoursy = 23;
           daysy--;
      }
      if(daysy == -1){
           daysy = 0;
      }

      timez.innerHTML = "<span class=''>"+daysy+"D</span><span class=''> "+hoursy+"H</span><span class=''> "+minutesy+"M</span><span class=''> "+secondsy+"S</span>";
      setTimeout(countdowny,1000);   
      }
  }

  var daysy=3;hoursy=3;minutesy=3;secondsy=3;
    var timez = document.getElementById("timez"+m);
    countdowny();
    m++;

      var daysy=2;hoursy=2;minutesy=2;secondsy=2;
    var timez = document.getElementById("timez"+m);
    countdowny();
    m++;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think the whole design is broken. You should consider to reuse an existing countdown widget. ([The simplest possible JavaScript countdown timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618355/the-simplest-possible-javascript-countdown-timer?rq=1))

In your specific case,the issue is your setTimeout. It will run your countdowny method again and again, but always with the global varibales.

So you'd need to refactor and give the element you want to update (and the remaining time) into the countdown function.

```
function countdowny(element, remainingTime) {
   if(remainingTime.daysy == 0 && remainingTime.hoursy == 0 && remainingTime.minutesy == 0 && remainingTime.secondsy == 0){
      //seconds = 0;
      element.innerHTML = "Auction Ended";
   }
   else{
      //Calc date as before
      element.innerHTML = "<span class=''>"+remainingTime.daysy+"D</span><span class=''> "+remainingTime.hoursy+"H</span><span class=''> "+remainingTime.minutesy+"M</span><span class=''> "+remainingTime.secondsy+"S</span>";
      setTimeout(countdowny,1000, element, remainingTime);   
  }
}

var remainingTime = { daysy:3, hoursy: 3, minutesy:3, secondsy:3 };
var timez = document.getElementById("timez"+m);
countdowny(timez, remainingTime);
```

Comment: OK... Got it working now... One change though the var object should be secondsy:3 not secondsy=3.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```js
timedown("May 20, 2050 17:00:25",'demo');
timedown("May 20, 2019 17:00:25",'demo1');
function timedown(ti,id){
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date(ti).getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = (days!=0 ? days + "d " : '') + (hours!= 0 ? hours + "h " : '')
    + (minutes != 0 ? minutes + "m " : '') + seconds + "s ";
    
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
}
```

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top:0px;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
```

countdown for days hour min second

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But as u can see this was asked one year ago and I got the solution to it back then only. Will use ur approach next time around. Thanks anyways.