# MomentJS countdown with diff

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs, setinterval

I am constructing a session timeout as part of a web application using the MomentJS library. What I have so far (below) is the `timeToExpire` difference (in seconds) from when the user logged in and when the session will expire. However when displaying a countdown clock using `setInterval`, the `diff` is **NOT** recalculated each second and instead the clock is never updated.

Could someone point me in the right direction to what is going wrong?

```js
const access_ttl = 3600;

const now = moment();

const login_timestamp = moment('2017-02-19 17:31:58+00:00');
const expire_timestamp = login_timestamp.add(access_ttl, 's');

const timeToExpire = expire_timestamp.diff(now, 'seconds');

function displayClock(inputSeconds) {
  const sec_num = parseInt(inputSeconds.toString(), 10);
  const hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
  const minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
  const seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);
  let hoursString = '';
  let minutesString = '';
  let secondsString = '';
  hoursString = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours.toString();
  minutesString = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes.toString();
  secondsString = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds.toString();
  return hoursString + ':' + minutesString + ':' + secondsString;
}

function timer() {
  $('.output').html(`Expires in: ${displayClock(timeToExpire)}`)
}

setInterval(timer, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: There are very much simpler countdown timers, e.g. [*The simplest possible JavaScript countdown timer?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618355/the-simplest-possible-javascript-countdown-timer). Note that *setInterval* does not run at exactly the specified delay, so your clock will slowly drift and appear to skip a second from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not updating the now() or timeToExpire values and so the value you are passing to displayClock is always the same.

Link to complete JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xzyjdb1g/2/

```
var now, timeToExpire;

function updateTime() {

  now = moment();

  timeToExpire = expire_timestamp.diff(now, 'seconds');
}

function timer() {
    updateTime();
  $('.output').html(`Expires in: ${displayClock(timeToExpire)}`)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info