# I want to make a game to count the number of clicks on the image in 1 minute

Tags: javascript, html

I've made this code to make a game that counts the number of clicks on the moving image .. but i can't make the Countdown or the counter .. i want when the user press start the game an countdown begins .. and every click on the image the number in (the counter) increased by one .. Thnx

```js
var x_position = 0 ; 
var theSpace = document.getElementById("gamespace");
var textt=document.getElementById("text");
var theMission = document.createTextNode(" - Press the tree as fast as you can ");
var theTree = document.createElement("img");
var moving;

function movingf() {
  theSpace.appendChild(theTree);
  theTree.style.left=Math.floor(Math.random() * 401) + "px";
  theTree.style.right=Math.floor(Math.random() * 401) + "px";
  theTree.style.top=Math.floor(Math.random() * 401) + "px";
  theTree.style.bottom=Math.floor(Math.random() * 401) + "px";
  moving=setTimeout(movingf,500);
  theTree.addEventListener("click",theCounter);
}

function theGame() {
  textt.style.clear="both";
  theTree.setAttribute("src","http://franklinccc.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/ccc-tree-logo.jpg");
  theTree.style.position="absolute";
  theSpace.appendChild(theTree);
  textt.appendChild(theMission);
  moving=setTimeout(movingf,50);
  theTree.onclick = theCounter();
}

function theCounter() {
  var time = 0; 
  time = time + 1 ; 
  var theCount = document.getElementById("times").innerHTML=time;
}
```

```css
#gamespace{
  border:2px solid black ;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  top:215px;}
  p{position:absolute;
  border:1px solid black;}
  button{position:absolute;
  top:60px;}
  #here{position:absolute;
  top:45px;
}
```

```html
<h1> PICTURE GAME .. </h1>
<button id="start" onclick="theGame()"> Press here to start the game</button>
<div id="here">
<form action="/action_page.php" id="here">
The countdown :
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="0" >
The counter :
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="0">
</form> 
</div>
<p id="text" style="top:170px"></p>
<div id="gamespace" style="position:absolute">  </div>
```

Comment: if you let `var time = 0;` inside the function `theCounter`, it will be reset each time there is a click, you should move it outside the function, also, it should be `theTree.onclick = theCounter;` or else you bind the result and not the function (to start with, there might be other errors)

Comment: Why don't you try debugging your code? Add a break point in the browser and step through your code

Comment: Just a point to note: Your `<style>` should be either in the `<head>` or `<body>` but not between them.

Comment: Ok i've solved the counter problem .. i want to know how to make a countdown when press start the game

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your javascript :

> "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null",

here :

```
var theCount = document.getElementById("times").innerHTML=time;
```

You have no element with the id = "times", so if you want the `<p>` element to contain the count, change the line to :

```
var theCount = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=time;
```

Also, theCounter() function should be like this :

```
 function theCounter() {  
            time = time + 1 ; 
     document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=time;
          }
```

```js
      var x_position = 0 ; 
      var theSpace = document.getElementById("gamespace");
      var textt=document.getElementById("text");
      var theMission = document.createTextNode(" - Press the tree as fast as you can ");
      var theTree = document.createElement("img");
      var moving ;
      var time = 0;
      function movingf() {
        theSpace.appendChild(theTree);
        theTree.style.left=Math.floor(Math.random() * 401) + "px";
        theTree.style.right=Math.floor(Math.random() * 401) + "px";
        theTree.style.top=Math.floor(Math.random() * 401) + "px";
        theTree.style.bottom=Math.floor(Math.random() * 401) + "px";
        moving=setTimeout(movingf,500);
        theTree.addEventListener("click",theCounter);
      }
      function theGame() {
        textt.style.clear="both";
        theTree.setAttribute("src","http://franklinccc.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/ccc-tree-logo.jpg");
        theTree.style.position="absolute";
        theSpace.appendChild(theTree);
        textt.appendChild(theMission);
        moving=setTimeout(movingf,50);
        theTree.onclick = theCounter();
      }
      function theCounter() {  
        time = time + 1 ; 
 document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=time;
      }
```

```css
#gamespace {
      border: 2px solid black ;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      top: 215px;
    }
    p {
      position: absolute;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    button {
      position: absolute;
      top: 60px;
    }
    #here {
      position: absolute;
      top: 45px;
    }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> PICTURE GAME .. </h1>
    <button id="start" onclick="theGame()"> Press here to start the game</button>
    <div id="here">
      <form action="/action_page.php" id="here">
        The countdown :
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="0" >
        The counter :
        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="0">
      </form> 
    </div>
    <p id="text" style="top:170px"></p>
    <div id="gamespace" style="position:absolute">  </div>

  </body>
```

Comment: Thnx i've solved this problem .. i need now know how to make a countdown .. Thnx

Comment: @tareq take a look at this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618355/the-simplest-possible-javascript-countdown-timer

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to reset your counter inside the `theCounter` function each time it was called, also tried to set `innerHTML` of element with id that was not in your markup. After fixing this this you can use [`setInterval`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html#dom-windowtimers-setinterval) to implement timer countdown:

```js
var x_position = 0 ; 
var theSpace = document.getElementById("gamespace");
var textt=document.getElementById("text");
var theMission = document.createTextNode(" - Press the tree as fast as you can ");
var theTree = document.createElement("img");
var moving;

function movingf() {
  theTree.style.left=Math.floor(Math.random() * 401) + "px";
  theTree.style.right=Math.floor(Math.random() * 401) + "px";
  theTree.style.top=Math.floor(Math.random() * 401) + "px";
  theTree.style.bottom=Math.floor(Math.random() * 401) + "px";
}

var clicks = 0, gameTimer, movingfTimer, timeleft; 

theSpace.appendChild(theTree);

function theGame() {
  clicks = 0; 
  timeleft = 30;
  document.getElementById("times").value = clicks;
  document.getElementById("countdown").value = timeleft;
  textt.style.clear="both";
  theTree.setAttribute("src","http://franklinccc.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/ccc-tree-logo.jpg");
  theTree.style.position="absolute";
  theSpace.appendChild(theTree);
  textt.appendChild(theMission);
  theTree.addEventListener("click", theCounter);
  movingf();
  clearInterval(movingfTimer);
  clearInterval(gameTimer);
  movingfTimer = setInterval(movingf, 500);
  gameTimer = setInterval(function(){
    timeleft--;
    document.getElementById("countdown").value = timeleft;
    if(timeleft <= 0){
      clearInterval(gameTimer);
      clearInterval(movingfTimer);  
      theTree.removeEventListener("click", theCounter);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function theCounter() {
  clicks++; 
  document.getElementById("times").value = clicks;
}
```

```css
#gamespace {
  border:2px solid black ;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  top:215px;
}
  
p {
  position:absolute;
  border:1px solid black;
}
  
button {
  position:absolute;
  top:60px;
}
  
#here {
  position:absolute;
  top:45px;
}
```

```html
<h1> PICTURE GAME .. </h1>
<button id="start" onclick="theGame()"> Press here to start the game</button>
<div id="here">
<form action="/action_page.php" id="here">
The countdown :
<input type="text" name="countdown" id="countdown" />
The counter :
<input type="text" name="times" id="times" value="0" />
</form> 
</div>
<p id="text" style="top:170px"></p>
<div id="gamespace" style="position:absolute">  </div>
```