# javascript multiple variable assignment in one line

Tags: javascript

so i was checking @robbmj 's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618355/the-simplest-possible-javascript-countdown-timer?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), and i came across the following code:

```
var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
```

and another one here:

```
var start = Date.now(),
    diff,
    minutes,
    seconds;
```

I have never been to that code before. Could someone please explain what those two lines of code does or at least how to read them ?

Comment: E.g. `var timer = duration, minutes = x, seconds = y;` ... `minutes` and `seconds` is declared but w/o any initial values

Comment: Those are just declarations.  `diff`, `minutes`, and `seconds` will still be `undefined`.  This can help make `var` declarations more obvious since you will have to worry about hoisting.

Comment: the first one set a var timer = duration and then 2 null / undefined vars - minutes and seconds.  The second  sets start as the current date and then sets three null / undefined vars in the scope.  Basically if you follow your variable declaration with a comma, it means you can go directly into declaring another variable in that scope without the need for saying `var` again: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: It's just this code: `var timer = duration; var minutes; var seconds;` condensed a little, `timer` is set to `duration`, `minutes` and `seconds` are undefined. Same thing applies to the second example, where `start` is defined as the value of `Date.now()` and the other variables are "initialized"

Comment: A good references for what is happening is documentation for the [`comma operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). A side note though on that style: it came into style before any of the build tools that now minify deliverable code automatically were available. In effect it was used as a way of manually minifying code (no need to write the extra `var x; ` for every declaration).

Comment: So it was that simple!! Thank you LGSon , zero298 , pete , luca :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write

```
var start = Date.now(),
diff,
minutes,
seconds;
```

as

```
var start = Date.now();
var diff;
var minutes;
var seconds;
```

So you can declare multiple variables in one line as in code snippet 1 where we are initialising `start` but only declaring other variables.

You can initialise multiple in one line like

```
var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
```

Comment: @jes Welcome :)

Comment: e.g. timer = 1; so `--timer < 0` will be `false`. --timer will first decrement timer and then it will compare as compared to `timer -- < 0` will first compare and then decrement.

Comment: yes I just read in here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_(.2B) big thanks to you again :))

Answer (score 5):

You can also use destructuring like this:

```
let [a, b, c] = [0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The First line creates 3 variables: `timer`, `minutes` and `seconds`.
but is assigning the value of the variable `duration` to variable timer.

the same story in example 2, just separated with line breaks.

It is a shortened way of saying

```
var timer = duration;
var minutes;
var seconds;
```

Comment: `var a = 0` is not the same as `var a;`!

Comment: Yes, that's true, sorry.

Comment: Thank you @JacobSchneider :)

Comment: No worries. Pleased to help.

Answer (score 0):

your second example just separated with line breaks.

define multiple variables on a single line annoying to remove the first or last declaration because they contain the var keyword and semicolon. And every time you add a new declaration, you have to change the semicolon in the old line to a comma.

**As a result, define multiple variables on a single line not recommended**

using it

```
var timer = duration;
var minutes = 0;
var seconds = 0;
```

instead of

```
var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
```