# what does Array do in this Javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I have seen a bit of code similar to this demonstration purpose function, somewhere:

```
function Pract() {
   let a = Array, b;
   b = 1;
   return b;
}
console.log(Pract())
// Output: 1
```

However, when I remove *Array* from the *a* variable it shows an error:
// And I know this is because *b* is not defined, but so does *b* in let a = **Array**, b;

```
function Pract() {
    let a = b;
    b = 1;
    return b;
}
console.log(Pract())
// Output: Error
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `let a = Array, b;` declares two variables `a` and `b` and initializes `a` with the value `Array`. `let a = b;` declares only one variable `a` and reads undeclared `b`. _"what does Array do in this Javascript function?"_ nothing.

Comment: and [What does variable declaration with multiple comma separated values mean (e.g. var a = b,c,d;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076750/what-does-variable-declaration-with-multiple-comma-separated-values-mean-e-g-v) or [javascript multiple variable assignment in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49984471/javascript-multiple-variable-assignment-in-one-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let a = Array, b;` declares two variables, `a` and `b`, and sets the value of `a` equal to the `Array` function (`b` is left with a value of `undefined`). There are no issues with this and it doesn't really have anything to do with `Array`. You could set `a` to any other value, or not set it at all, like `let a, b;`

However, `let a = b;` declares only `a` and attempts to set its value to the value of `b`, which has not been defined anywhere. Thus there is a `ReferenceError`. This would work, though, if you put `b = 1` before `let a = b;`.

Answer (score 4):

The code:

```
let a = Array, b;
```

Is same as

```
let a = Array;
let b;
```

Which is the same as

```
let a = Array;
let b = undefined;
```

So in the original code you define `a` as an array and `b` as an `undefined` variable. Then a value of 1 is assigned the the variable `b`, and the variable is the returned. The variable `a` is never used.

In your code, when you do

```
  let a = b
```

You should get "b is not defined" error, since you're saying `a` should be something that has never been defined.

To simplify the code, you can simply do

```
function Pract() {
    let b = 1
    return b;
}
console.log(Pract())
```