# How to decrement timer value in js?

Tags: javascript

I have a code with me for decrementing a timer with count equal to `6` but I want to decrement the value of count with format `hrs:min:sec` like this `00:00:10`

```
function countdown() {
// starts countdown
if (count == 0) {
// time is up
} else {
count--;
t = setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);
}
};
```

where count will be 00:00:10 for 10 sec. How to decrement the timer ? Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The simplest possible JavaScript countdown timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618355/the-simplest-possible-javascript-countdown-timer)

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/20618517/4004879

Comment: how to get the value 10 from 00:00:10 ?

Comment: say that your value 00:00:10 is in a variable s . ie `s = '00:00:10'` . then use `sec = s.slice(-2)` since last 2 digit contains seconds

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do what you need:

```js
function showCountdown(countSeconds)
{  
   var countStatus = new Date(1000 * countSeconds).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
   document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Count: " + countStatus;
}
var count = 10;

function countdown() {
  // starts countdown
  if (count === 0) {
     return;
  }
  count--;
  setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
  showCountdown(count);
  
};

countdown();
```

```html
<div id="output">
</div>
```

I've updated the JSFiddle to format as HH:mm:ss
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8uhq0vej/7/