# How to stop javascript timer from resetting when it completes

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

I am building a form that a I need a simple 10 minute javascript countdown timer to display in.  I have found and am using the code at the top of the page here: [The simplest possible JavaScript countdown timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618355/the-simplest-possible-javascript-countdown-timer)  .. It does exactly what I need it to, but I need the timer not to reset when it reaches 00:00.  I am a novice when it comes to Javascript, so any help would be appreciated.

I looked through the posting on [The simplest possible JavaScript countdown timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618355/the-simplest-possible-javascript-countdown-timer) .. but was unable to see anyone that specifically talked about stopping the timer from resetting when it ended.

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 10,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

The timer works as I need it to, but it resets every time it reaches 0.  I just need it to start on page load and stop at 10 minutes.  I am just reminding my form users to save their draft every 10 minutes.

Comment: if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        } resets the timer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  I must be doing something wrong.. again my Java knowledge is limited.  I made the change, I thought suggested, but now when my timer reaches 00:00 the numbers starting going negative.

Comment: @TJLP Beware! Java and JavaScript are totaly different languages.

Comment: Right! Thank you Kai.  I'll ensure to specify going forward.  :)  So yes, my JavaScript experience/knowledge is extremely limited.  The forms I build are pretty straight forward and rarely use nothing more than HTML and CSS.  Any help on what I could be doing wrong would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help.  I found another piece of code that did the job for me.  I'll share below for anyone else to use.

```
  //Countdown Timer

  var startTime = 10; //set countdown in Minutes  
  var doneClass = "done";
  var blinkerClass = "blink";
  function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    var intervalLoop = setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        for(var i=0;i<display.length;i++){
          display[i].textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        }
        if (--timer < 0) {
          for(var i=0;i<display.length;i++){
            display[i].classList.add(doneClass);
            display[i].classList.add(blinkerClass);
            display[i].textContent = "Save Now";
          }
          clearInterval(intervalLoop);
        }
        }, 1000);
    }
window.onload = function () {
    var setMinutes = 60 * startTime,
    display = $('#timer');
    startTimer(setMinutes, display);
};

  //End Countdown timer
```

Here is the CSS referenced in the code above

```
.done {color: tomato !important; font-weight: bold;}
.blink {
  animation: blinker 1s step-start infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```