# How can I print value each second in for loop JS?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have the code:

```
function sleep(ms){
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            setTimeout(function(){
                resolve();
            },ms)
        });
    }
let str = 'abcdef';
for(let i=0;i<str.length;i++){
   sleep(1000);
   console.log(str[i]);
}
```

How can I print `str[i]` each 1 second? This is code example, `setInterval` don't solve my problem!

Comment: There really isn't a reason to be using a promise here... you could just use a recursive call

Comment: Any reason not to use `setInterval` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The simplest possible JavaScript countdown timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618355/the-simplest-possible-javascript-countdown-timer)

Comment: `function sleep (ms) { return new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(resolve, ms); }); }` would suffice, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Using ES7, you can wrap your for loop in an async function that waits for the `sleep` promise to be resolved.

```js
function sleep(ms){
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  });
}
    
let str = 'abcdef';

async function loop(){
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
await sleep(1000);
console.log(str[i]);
  }
}

loop()
```

Of course, you can make this function more flexible passing the string you want to loop over as argument.

```js
function sleep(ms){
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  });
}
    
async function logSlowly(string){
  for(let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
await sleep(1000);
console.log(string[i]);
  }
}

logSlowly('abcdef')
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let str = 'abcdef';
    for(let i=0;i<str.length;i++){
       setTimeout(function() {
         console.log(str[i])
    }, 1000 * i)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const str = 'mystring';
const printEveryOneSecond = (s) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
      setTimeout( () =>{
        console.log(s[i])
      }, i * 1000)
    }
}
printEveryOneSecond(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about the solution what you made. I guess what solves your issue is the following code snippet:

```js
(function () {
   let str = 'abcdef';
   let timing = 0;
   let printCharWithDelay = (character, timing) => {
      setTimeout(function() {
         console.log(character);
      }, timing);
   };
   
   for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      printCharWithDelay(str[i], timing);
      timing += 1000;
   }
})();
```

I have completely restructured your code, if you run it you will have the required result.

Basically the code delays printing the passed character with the calculated milliseconds. Obviously it can be simplified but this is a good example to understand how `setTimeout` behaves in this scenario.

To read further about window `setTimeout()` method follow the link [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Try to call sleep with **await** in front.
Like this:

```
await sleep(1000);
```

Please use the search function befor posting duplicates 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)

To use the rigth functionaly please take a look to the dokumentation at this link [here](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-sleep/)