# My JavaScript countdown timer is not properly functioning

Tags: javascript

My JavaScript timer is working bizarrely: it goes 3-2 and then abruptly it finishes (without going through step 1 and 0). Here is the code:

```js
var count = 3;
function countDown() {
  document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = count;
  if (count > 0) {
    count--
  }
  else {
    clearInterval(ncount);
    document.getElementById("count").style.display = "none"
  }
  var ncount = setInterval("countDown()", 1000);
}
```

```html
<form id="askName">
  <label> Enter your username: </label>
  <input id="input" type="text" required maxlength="10">
  <button type="button" onclick="countDown()"> Submit </button>
</form>
<h2 id="count"> </h2>
```

Why does this occur?

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618355/the-simplest-possible-javascript-countdown-timer

Comment: Maybe `setInterval("countDown()", 1000)` should be `setInterval(countDown, 1000)`?

Comment: Make `ncount` public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) is calling your function that spawns another `setInterval`, which causes the count to be decremented faster. You can use a inner function to avoid this issue.

```js
var count = 3;
function countDown() {
   function helper(){
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = count;
    if (count > 0) {
      count--;
    }  else {
      clearInterval(ncount);
      document.getElementById("count").style.display = "none"
    }
  }
  var ncount = setInterval(helper, 1000);
}
```

```html
<form id="askName">
  <label> Enter your username: </label>
  <input id="input" type="text" required maxlength="10">
  <button type="button" onclick="countDown()"> Submit </button>
</form>
<h2 id="count"> </h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

This Should work fine. I tried Changing the `setInterval` Time

```js
var count = 3;
    function countDown() {
        function helper() {
            document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = count;
            if (count > 0) {
                count--;
             } else {
                clearInterval(ncount);
                document.getElementById("count").style.display = "none";
        }
      }
      var ncount = setInterval(helper, 1020);
    }
```

```html
<form id="askName">
  <label> Enter your username: </label>
  <input id="input" type="text" required maxlength="10">
  <button type="button" onclick="countDown()"> Submit </button>
</form>
<h2 id="count"> </h2>
```