# javascript is not updating the timer after a while

Tags: javascript, html

I tested a simple timer code for showing timer in website. The timer working fine when i am on the page. But when I go the another page or site, after a while when I come back to the timer page i see that timer did not worked correctly in the interval.
Suppose I leave the page for 5 minutes. So when I will come back, I should see `00:05:00`. But it is displaying `00:01:00` (around).
But if I dont leave the page it is working fine.
What is the solution?

```js
timerElement = document.getElementById("time");
let seconds = 0, minutes = 0,  hours = 0;
timerInterval = setInterval(function() {
  seconds++;

  if (seconds === 60) {
    seconds = 0;
    minutes++;

    if (minutes === 60) {
      minutes = 0;
      hours++;
    }
  }

  const formattedTime = `${String(hours).padStart(2, "0")}:${String(minutes).padStart(2, "0")}:${String(seconds).padStart(2, "0")}`;
  timerElement.textContent = formattedTime;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<h1 id="time"></h1>
```

Even I deployed this on github page. But result is same.

Comment: Some browsers for example Microsoft Edge automatically put your tabs to sleep after some time of inactivity.

Comment: Firstly don't use things like `hours++` inside an interval, use the Date object and compare to some start Date.

Comment: _delay_ argument in `setInterval()` cannot be used for chronographic task.

Comment: if you want it to be really robust, don't increment seconds, but instead calculate your final datestamp and save that to localStorage. Then when displaying your counter always compare current datestamp to the one in localStorage to compute the seconds remaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setInterval` and `setTimeout` call their callback not in precise time. When a page is on a hidden tab the browser could postpone/throttle callbacks.

I would suggest to try `requestAnimationFrame` (which isn't called on a hidden tab which is good) and compare the current time to the timer's start time. Using `requestAnimationFrame` would give more precise the timer's updating on the screen.

Formatting could be done with `Intl.DateTimeFormat` (used here to simplify the example, needs some tweaks to handle hours > 24):

```js
const start = new Date, today = new Date;
today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
let running = true;

const format = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
  hourCycle: 'h23',
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit',
  second: '2-digit',  
  fractionalSecondDigits: 2
});
// add today's timestamp so the timezone would be properly handled
const timer = () => requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  $time.textContent = format.format(new Date - start + +today);
  running && timer();
});

timer();
console.log('started');
```

```css
button{
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor:pointer;
  background:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="$time" style="font-family:monospace"></h1>
<button onmousedown="running = false">Stop</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

this one will do the job of real elapsed time on reactivate window, with no error when it's in system standby

```js
const
  timerElement = document.querySelector('#timer-element')
, Digits2      = t => t<10 ? `0${t}` : t
, one_Sec      = 1000
, one_Min      = one_Sec * 60
, one_Hour     = one_Min * 60
, ZeroTime     = new Date().getTime()
  ;
setInterval(()=>
  {
  let tim = new Date().getTime() - ZeroTime
    , h   = Math.floor( tim / one_Hour)
    , m   = Math.floor((tim % one_Hour) / one_Min )
    , s   = Math.floor((tim % one_Min ) / one_Sec )
    ;
  timerElement.textContent = `${Digits2(h)}:${Digits2(m)}:${Digits2(s)}`
  },500);
```

```html
<h1 id="timer-element"></h1>
```

If you look for more elaborate : [see there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63320897/how-do-i-do-a-continuous-timing-hour-minute-second/63321520#63321520)