# Changing the date on a countdown when distance is < 0

Tags: javascript, date, if-statement, countdown

I have a timer to countdown to a date and time.
What I'd like it to do is that after it hits 0 with the first date, it would then start counting down to the next date.

I am not at all good at code so there might be the most simple answer to this but i have not been able to find it.

I tried making an `if` statement but I couldn't find what actually would tell it to do what I want it to.

```
    function countDown() {
    var countDownDate = new Date("feb 10, 2024 23:24:00").getTime();
  
    var x = setInterval(function() {
  
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
  
    var h = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 ));
    var m = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var s = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    h = addZero(h);
    m = addZero(m);
    s = addZero(s);
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s ;


    }, 1000);
 
    function addZero(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  
    return i;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you need to achieve ?

Comment: don't use `setTimeout()` since it's not precise : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77130682/javascript-is-not-updating-the-timer-after-a-while/77130955#77130955

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to add one calendar day to `countDownDate`, preserving the same time of day, then you could do this:

```
if (distance < 0) {
    countDownDate.setDate(countDownDate.getDate() + 1);
    distance = countDownDate - now;
}
```

Comment: The goal is to add one hour to the count down. How would that differ?

Comment: You would just add `60 * 60 * 1000` to `countDownDate`.  You wouldn't need to worry about time zones or DST for that.