# Function undefined though it works in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript

I am really just copypasting the exact same "code" of that fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7b0ky186/ to my **local** html-file and have nothing else around it. But while it works nice in JSFiddle I get an error when starting that function within my console saying that `Uncaught ReferenceError: CountDownTimer is not defined`

What do I do wrong there?

```
<body>
<a id="startTimer">Start Count Down</a>
<div>Registration schliesst in <span id="displayTimer"></span> minutes!</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var display = document.querySelector('#displayTimer'),
            timer = new CountDownTimer(5),
            timeObj = CountDownTimer.parse(5);

        format(timeObj.minutes, timeObj.seconds);

        timer.onTick(format);

        document.querySelector('#startTimer').addEventListener('click', function() {
            timer.start();
        });

        function format(minutes, seconds) {
            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
            display.textContent = minutes + ':' + seconds;
        }
    };

</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The simplest possible JavaScript countdown timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618355/the-simplest-possible-javascript-countdown-timer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the left side of jsFiddle.org you see "Resources `1`". You can click on it which will show all "resources" which are added. You can then copy the links right from there. In this case you need [countdowntimer.js](https://cdn.rawgit.com/robbmj/simple-js-countdown-timer/master/countdowntimer.js)

[image]

When you have the URL of the missing .js you can add it like so just before your `<script>` tag

```
<!-- your HTML goes here -->
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/robbmj/simple-js-countdown-timer/master/countdowntimer.js"></script>
<!-- your <script> and js things go here -->
```