# Unsupported operand types: Illuminate\Support\Carbon - Illuminate\Support\Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-9, php-carbon

I have made this method for sending a temporary code to user's mobile phone number for verifying his account:

```
public function signInWithToken()
    {
        if(Session::has('nextStep') && Session::has('foundUser')) {
            $user = User::where('usr_mobile_phone', Session::get('foundUser'))->first();
            if(Session::has('codeSent')){
                $nowTime = now();
                $sentTime = Session::get('codeSent');
                if($nowTime >= $sentTime){
                    $user->activeCode()->delete();
                    Session::forget('codeSent');
                }
            }else{
                $code = ActiveCode::generateCode($user);
                $user->notify(new ActiveCodeNotification($code, Session::get('foundUser')));
                Session::put('codeSent', now()->addMinutes(10));
            }

            return view('frontend.auth.token');
        }else{
            abort(404);
        }
    }
```

So for the first time, a code generates and the session `codeSent` will also be submitted and its value is 10 minutes above the current time.

Then I also need to check if this session was already submitted, then it has to subtract the `$nowTime` from `$sentTime` to find out if the code was generated **more than 10 minutes ago and is too old**: (so the code must be deleted from the DB and the session must be forgotten)

```
$nowTime = now();
$sentTime = Session::get('codeSent');
if($nowTime >= $sentTime){
    $user->activeCode()->delete();
    Session::forget('codeSent');
}
```

But this code won't run and return this error:

### **Unsupported operand types: Illuminate\Support\Carbon - Illuminate\Support\Carbon**

Value of `nowTime` var:

[image]

Value of `sentTime` var (set the *currentTime* + 10 minutes as the expire time of session `codeSent`):

[image]

And I know this is because those `sentTime` && `nowTime` variable values can not be subtracted from eachother somehow.

But really don't know what is the correct way for doing this check!

So if you know, please let me know, I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Carbon diffInSeconds like the code below(untested)
first you need to parse times with carbon
then use this:

```
$totalDuration = $finishTime->diffInSeconds($startTime);
// 21
```

Comment: Do you know how to show this `$totalDuration` value live on blade so that user will see how many seconds left?

Comment: you need to use javascript or jquery to show the time left.

Comment: @Pouya you can return it with the view('frontend.someView', compact('totalDuration')) and use jQuery to show it/keep requesting it or static in html

Comment: I have asked a bounty question about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74699048/how-to-show-a-variable-which-is-changing-per-second-on-a-blade-live

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find the difference in minutes
You can use it:

```
$nowTime = now(); 
$sentTime = Session::get('codeSent'); 
if($nowTime->diffInMinutes($sentTime)>10)
{ $user->activeCode()->delete(); Session::forget('codeSent'); }
```

Comment: Thanks, I have one more problem related to this which is also on bounty, please check it out: I have asked a bounty question about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74699048/how-to-show-a-variable-which-is-changing-per-second-on-a-blade-live

Comment: @zorehda Hi pal, did you delete your answer on the bounty question, I was going to accept it but now I don't see any answer from you on that question!

Comment: did you use it? did it work?

Comment: Yes I have made some changes on it and the time setInterval itself works great but I have a problem with the Controller which does not delete the `codeSent` session. You may post your answer once again

Comment: I'll post it again