# Javascript what does the | 0 do

Tags: javascript

When you open up your console and type in any decimal number for example `5.123` and add `| 0` after it, it will be rounded to `5`.

Somehow, if you change it to `| 2` , it will write down `7`.

```js
var test1 = 5.123 | 0 ; // will be 5
var test2 = 5.123 | 2 ; // will be 7
var test3 = 5.123 | 4 ; // will be 5 again
```

Can someone explain to my what is happening above and also, can I use this instead of parseInt?

Comment: its a bitwise operator see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bitwise operator... to quote [MDN on Javascript operators and expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators):

> Bitwise operators treat their operands as a sequence of 32 bits (zeroes and ones), rather than as decimal, hexadecimal, or octal numbers. For example, the decimal number nine has a binary representation of 1001. Bitwise operators perform their operations on such binary representations, but they return standard JavaScript numerical values.

What happens, is that the operator treats the number as a 32 bit integer; so `5.123` is treated as:

```
 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101
```

(the decimal part is thrown out) and 0 is treated as

```
 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Then the `OR` function compares the two, and writes a `1` if either number has a `1`.

So using the bitwise `OR` with a decimal number and zero is essentially a way to discard the decimal part and retain the integer part.

Your other example with two is (insignificant `0`s have been removed):

```
 0101 (5)
 0010 (2)
 ---- ORed
 0111 (7)
```

and the example with 4:

```
 0101 (5)
 0100 (4)
 ---- ORed
 0101 (5)
```

You can use it to convert to discard the decimal part of a number - see [Using bitwise OR 0 to floor a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487977/using-bitwise-or-0-to-floor-a-number)