# Javascript pipe in math to get Math.floor without using Math.floor

Tags: javascript, math

I just saw this shortcut being used in some JavaScript.

```
(9 + 2) / 2|0; // results in 5
```

When you do the normal math it results in 5.5.

How come the top expression is resulting in Math.floor((9+2)/2)?
Can someone point in in the direction of what that pipe is doing, I don't understand the shortcut.

Comment: it's a bitwise "or"

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487977/using-bitwise-or-0-to-floor-a-number

Comment: [List of JS operators...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single pipe | is [BitWise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7c_%28Bitwise_OR%29).
Bitwise operator only allow integer values, so after decimal point value is discarded.

`Bitwise OR` operator | takes 2 bit patterns, and perform OR operations on each pair of corresponding bits. 
The following example will explain it.

```
1010                            
1100       
----------bitwise or
1110
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Firstly the result of `(9+2)/2` is `5.5` in JavaScript
2. Then it's applied a bitwise `Or` operation. For JavaScript, the bitwise operations don't work directly on the 64-bit representations. Instead, the value is converted into a 32-bit integer, which means `5.5` to `5`, then the result of `5|0` is `5`.