# Explanation [Randoming List]

Tags: javascript, html, list

The javascript is randoming the list..
and i don't understand how it works, please help me explain how the javascript work in very details.

```
<ul id="name">
    <li>Sunday</li>
    <li>Monday</li>
    <li>Tuesday</li>
    <li>Wednesday</li>
    <li>Thursday</li>
    <li>Friday</li>
    <li>Saturday</li>
</ul>

     <script>

var ul = document.getElementById("name"), 
    temp = ul.cloneNode(true), 
    i = temp.children.length + 1;

while( i-- > 0 )
    temp.appendChild( temp.children[Math.random() * i |0] );

ul.parentNode.replaceChild(temp, ul);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//saving <ul> element wiсh id is 'name' to the ul variable
var ul = document.getElementById("name"),  
    //cloning this ul and all its child elements to the temp variable; 
    //cloneNode(true) means deep copy, cloneNode(false) copies only the node 
    temp = ul.cloneNode(true),   
    // we will start from the end of the child nodes array and go down          
    i = temp.children.length + 1; 

//at each iteration we will decrement i and compare it to 0
while (i-- > 0)
    //while this condition is true we take a random node from the child elements array;
    //here we use Math.random() to generate a random number from 0 to 1, 
    //multiply it by i to get a number from 0 to i and then use bitwise OR with 0
    //to convert this floating point number to an integer (see below for more details);
    //and then we append this random child to the temp; if a node already exists
    //in the DOM, then appendNode will remove it before appending, so we just replace
    //the nodes in random order
    temp.appendChild(temp.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);

//and finally we replace the old ul with a new one
ul.parentNode.replaceChild(temp, ul);
```

For more information about bitwise OR take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487977/using-bitwise-or-0-to-floor-a-number)

Answer (score 0):

First, you [get the `ul` tag, which id is name](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp): `ul = document.getElementById("name")`

---

You [clone the node](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp): `temp = ul.cloneNode(true)`,

---

You'll get how many children (`li` tags) your `ul` have: `i = temp.children.length + 1` (+1 to check with 0 on loop),

---

The while loop will decrement x (`x--`) and check if it's bigger than 0: `(i--) > 0`, and append one [random](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) children to the cloned node: `temp.appendChild( temp.children[Math.random() * i |0] )`

---

In the end, you just [replace all your ul child with your temp (cloned) childs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_replacechild.asp): `ul.parentNode.replaceChild(temp, ul)`.