# Using a bitwise AND 1

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

If x is a floating point number, does

```
y = x & 1
```

have a purpose other than checking whether x is odd?

I just read [Using bitwise OR 0 to floor a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487977/using-bitwise-or-0-to-floor-a-number) and wonder, are there other interesting bitwise manipulations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `x` is logically floating point (not intended to be an integer value before the test), `& 1` has exactly one purpose: To determine if the truncated value of `x` is odd (it's a combined truncation and bitwise test). It's not saying if `x` is odd (`-2.9` is neither odd nor even, nor is `-3.9`, and they give opposite results), and it's not just truncating (because it throws away all but one bit of data); the test is intrinsically combining both effects, and as such, is not useful for anything else when `x` is an arbitrary floating point value.

As other answer(s) mention, bitwise operations have other legitimate uses, e.g. cryptography, or repurposing an integer as a vector of boolean flags, but that's only relevant for logically integer values; performing floating point math and then relying on specific integer values after truncation, without rounding, is a terrible idea, and will bite you when the result ends up being `X.9999999999999999999999994` when you expected it to be (and under "grade school" math, it would be) `X+1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use bitwise operators to encode options and flags.

ie. Encoding car features

```
automaticWindows = 0b1; // 1
manualTransmission = 0b10; // 2
hasAC = 0b100; // 4
hasHeater = 0b1000; // 8
```

If my car has automatic window and AC, but nothing else, then i'd do this:

```
myCarOptions = automaticWindows | hasAC;
```

Then to check if some random car has AC I can do:

```
if (randomCarOption & hasAC) {
  // do something... like turn on AC
}
```

At the end of the day bitwise operators simply allow you to do logic with the various bits which is the core of how computing works.

Comment: The OP presupposes that `x` is a logical floating point number. You wouldn't use a logical floating point number to store flags. This is a reasonable use for bitwise-and, but in that case, the value would be logically integer the whole time or the flags are meaningless.