# Why Date.now() | 0 not same as Date.now()

Tags: javascript, typescript, numbers

Int Number | 0 will same as source number

But why `Date.now() | 0` not same as `Date.now()`

```js
let t = Date.now()
console.log((t | 0) === t)
```

Comment: `| 0` converts to a 32 bit integer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using bitwise OR 0 to floor a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487977/using-bitwise-or-0-to-floor-a-number)

Comment: Did you confuse `Date.now() || 0` with `Date.now() | 0`? The two operators are very different.

Comment: @Luaan not sure why you'd ever use `Date.now() || 0`. Surely, you will never get a falsy result from executing that method.

Comment: @VLAZ Of course not from `Date.now()` itself, I assume the `Date.now()` is just used here to provide a date value, that would be an argument/local in the actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitwise operators operate on *bits* as represented by 32 zeros and/or ones. If the number being operated on is outside this range, the result will likely be unintuitive.

For bitwise OR, this limit is reached once the number is `2 ** 31 - 1`:

```js
const test = num => console.log((num | 0) === num);
test(2 ** 31 - 1)
test(2 ** 31)
test(2 ** 31 + 1)
```

`Date.now` returns the number of milliseconds between the epoch and now, which is a large number (`1583486012561` or thereabouts), much larger than the upper limit of `2147483647`.