# Unusual behavior of this key word in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have following code snippet which should return all the team names of a agile team. But code returns `undefined`. I have already tried `let _this = this;` and replaced `this` with `_this` but no result. Can anyone help me with this please.

```
let teamSelector = {
  teams: ['Team Alpha', 'Team Beta', 'Team Delta'],
  selectTeam: function(members){
    // let _this = this; 
    return members.map((member)=>{
      return `${member} is on ${this.teams[Math.random() * 3]}`;
    });
  }
};

teamSelector.selectTeam(['Anna','Jhon','Kevin','Lesli']);
```

Comment: `Math.random() * 3` is return a float number you need to get floor of it. `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math.random() returns fractional numbers. If you want an array index you need integers

see [Using bitwise OR 0 to floor a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487977/using-bitwise-or-0-to-floor-a-number/)

```js
let teamSelector = {
  teams: ['Team Alpha', 'Team Beta', 'Team Delta'],
  selectTeam: function(members) {
    // let _this = this; 
    return members.map((member) => {
      return `${member} is on ${this.teams[Math.random() * 3 | 0]}`;
    });
  }
};

console.log(teamSelector.selectTeam(['Anna', 'Jhon', 'Kevin', 'Lesli']));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass default 0 in math.random

```
let teamSelector = {
      teams: ['Team Alpha', 'Team Beta', 'Team Delta'],
      selectTeam: function(members){
        // let _this = this; 
        return members.map((member)=>{
          return `${member} is on ${this.teams[Math.random() * 3 | 0]}`;
        });
      }
    };

    teamSelector.selectTeam(['Anna','Jhon','Kevin','Lesli']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The value generated from `Math.random` is a float number so it will never reference an array index from `this.teams`, hence `undefined` value.

What you need to do is generate a random number using `Math.random() * this.teams.length` so that it will never generate an index value larger than the array size itself. You then need to use `Math.floor` to round this down as your `Math.random` generates a float number.

```
let teamSelector = {
  teams: ["Team Alpha", "Team Beta", "Team Delta"],
  selectTeam: function (members) {
    return members.map((member) => 
    `${member} is on ${
        this.teams[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.teams.length)]
      }`
    );
  },
};

teamSelector.selectTeam(["Anna", "John", "Kevin", "Lesli"]);
```

Just a side note too - arrow functions implicitly return so you don't need to `return` inside the map. However you do need to use `return` for the `map` itself to keep the context of `this` inside the block scope of the object. You will see, if you implicitly return the `map` then `this` will reference the `window` object or a higher up block scope such as the class implementation.