# JavaScript - Child objects called by functions to update child objects

Tags: javascript, function, object, scope

I am learning about objects and their scopes, I got confused and decided to make a D&D pathfinder character sheet for practice.

I made the character sheet as an object, child objects for ability scores, strength/dexterity/intelligence/etc... and then base and modifier values.

in D&D you use your base value to calculate your modifier value and the modifier is used throughout the game. The calculation for modifier is `(base - 10) / 2`

as i run this i only get 0 when called `console.log(characterSheet.abilityScore.strength.modifier)`

I assume my confusion is about my understanding of the scope range between the function and modifier/base. but I'm not sure where to start.

```
const characterSheet = {
  abilityScore: {
    strength: {
      base: 2,
      modifier: 0,
      calcMod: function () {
        this.modifier = Math.floor((this.base - 10) / 2);
      },
    },
    dexterity: {
      base: 8,
      modifier: 0,
      calcMod: function () {
        this.modifier = Math.floor((this.base - 10) / 2);
      },
    },
    intelligence: {
      base: 16,
      modifier: 0,
      calcMod: function () {
        this.modifier = Math.floor((this.base - 10) / 2);
      },
    },
  },
}
```

I have also tried placing the function in the global scope but always returns NaN.

```js
const characterSheet = {
  abilityScore: {
    strength: {
      base: 2,
      modifier: function () {
        return calcMod(this.base);
      },
    strength: {
      base: 8,
      modifier: function () {
        return calcMod(this.base);
      },
    },
    strength: {
      base: 16,
      modifier: function () {
        return calcMod(this.base);
      },
    },
  },
}};
function calcMod(val) {
  return Math.floor((val - 10) / 2);
}

console.log(calcMod(characterSheet.abilityScore.strength));
```

Comment: Add the code that calls `calcMod()`

Comment: After I call `characterSheet.abilityScore.strength.calcMod()`, when I log `characterSheet.abilityScore.strength.modifier` it shows `-4`.

Comment: @MisterJojo I was referencing for when I make a function outside the object.

Comment: @Barmar am I building this wrong then? I don't want to call the function every time I want to call the modifier. wouldn't that be repeating myself?

Comment: @mastaSabin Please [edit] your question to show the code where you make the function "outside the object".

Comment: @mastaSabin If you don't want to repeat yourself, use one function that builds these objects: `{strength: buildScore(2), dexterity: buildScore(8), intelligence: buildScore(16)}`

Comment: @MisterJojo updated to include function outside of the object. also, do you mean pathfinder? It's D&D 3.6 basically

Comment: I don't know what is `D&D 3.6` is there a link which can explain this stuff?

Comment: @MisterJojo Doungens and Dragons https://dnd.wizards.com though I don't know if pathfinder is part of the Wizards company or not. I am referencing https://www.d20pfsrd.com/ for most of my info about pathfinder.

Comment: change `console.log(calcMod(characterSheet.abilityScore.strength));` to `console.log(calcMod(characterSheet.abilityScore.strength.base));`

Comment: ok, D&D stands for Dungeons and Dragons... I hardly play any games (I didn't even know what a sudoku was recently), next time try to conceive that everyone does not gravitate in the same universe as yours ;)

Comment: @MisterJojo I was mostly trying to keep the details related to JavaScript.

Comment: @Bergi how could I build this function? when I use it as you suggest it works as expected. but when i place modifier: `buildScore(this.base)` it returns NaN.

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to use it as I suggested. It's still not clear what other way you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use that... ?

```js
const characterSheet =
  { abilityScore: 
    { strength:
      { base      : 2
      , modifier  : 0
      }
    , dexterity: 
      { base      : 8
      , modifier  : 0
      }
    , intelligence: 
      { base      : 16
      , modifier  : 0
      }
    , calcMod ( ability )
      { 
      return this[ability].modifier = 0 | ((this[ability].base - 10) / 2);       
  } } } 

console.log( characterSheet.abilityScore.calcMod( 'strength' ) )

console.log( characterSheet.abilityScore.strength.modifier )
```

OR:

```js
const characterSheet =
  { abilityScore: 
    { strength     : { base :  2, modifier : 0 }
    , dexterity    : { base :  8, modifier : 0 }
    , intelligence : { base : 16, modifier : 0 }
  } };
  
function calcMod( val ) 
  {
  return val.modifier = 0 | ((val.base - 10) / 2);
  }

console.log( calcMod( characterSheet.abilityScore.strength ))
```

Comment: is that an or operator? `|`

Comment: @mastaSabin No, it's a [more concise alternative to `Math.floor`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7487977/1048572) which doesn't work properly for large numbers. I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
function buildScore(base) {
  return {
    base,
    modifier: Math.floor((base - 10) / 2),
  };
}
const characterSheet = {
  abilityScore: {
    strength: buildScore(2),
    dexterity: buildScore(8),
    intelligence: buildScore(16),
  },
};

console.log(characterSheet.abilityScore.strength);
```

No methods, no problems. You could also achieve something like this with getters, but it would be much more complicated.

Comment: ohh that looks pretty. I'll try that out now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *getter* for `modifier` that calls `calcMod()`. This calls a function to return the value of the property, so it can calculate it based on the current value of `this.base`.

```js
function calcMod(val) {
  return Math.floor((val - 10) / 2);
}

const characterSheet = {
  abilityScore: {
    strength: {
      base: 2,
      get modifier() {
        return calcMod(this.base);
      }
    },
    dexterity: {
      base: 8,
      get modifier() {
        return calcMod(this.base);
      }
    },
    intelligence: {
      base: 16,
      get modifier() {
        return calcMod(this.base);
      }
    },
  },
}

console.log(characterSheet.abilityScore.dexterity.modifier);
characterSheet.abilityScore.dexterity.base = 10;
console.log(characterSheet.abilityScore.dexterity.modifier);
```